# Xdocument does not exist in current context

Tags: c#, development-environment, infopath2010

I am building an infopath form, I added a button which job is to print. I have the following code but I am getting the following error

```
The name "thisXdocument" does not exist in current context.
```

code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.InfoPath;
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.SemiTrust;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

namespace SubmitPath
{
public partial class FormCode
{
public void InternalStartup()
    {
        EventManager.FormEvents.Submit += new SubmitEventHandler(FormEvents_Submit);

        ((ButtonEvent)EventManager.ControlEvents["CTRL3_5"]).Clicked += new ClickedEventHandler(CTRL3_5_Clicked);
    }
public void FormEvents_Submit(object sender, SubmitEventArgs e)
    { }
public void CTRL3_5_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        thisXdocument.PrintOut();
    }
  }
}
```

i want to print but i cant cause that error!

please help me!

Comment: at this line: `thisXdocument.PrintOut();
`

Comment: Well, That's kinda obvious. There's no definition of `thisXdocument` in your class whatsoever. what is it? have you created it in the design mode?

Comment: ` XDocument thisXdocument = new XDocument();
            thisXdocument.PrintOut();` this brings me a new error

Comment: now im getting this error `microsoft.office.interop.infopath.semitrust.xdocument Wrapper is inaccessible due to its protection level`

Comment: seen this http://www.office-forums.com/threads/thisxdocument-is-not-declared.97564/

Comment: no it not working man